# Jacoco branch missed after try-with-resources with no catch

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco, try-with-resources

I have a try-with-resources with no catch or finally.  I am able to get 100% line coverage but I am unable to cover 1 branch at line 249.  The branch is code from try-with-resources.

Notice that line 251 is covered (i.e., `return true`).  Notice that line 247 is covered and this throws an exception.

I wrote a test case that causes `Files.newInputStream()` to throw an `IOException`.  This did not cover the missing branch.

What test case am I missing?

[image: Java Code with Missed Branch After Try Block]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the contents of the try block to another method.

I wonder if the `return false` in the try block is causing the problem.